# How to implement inheritance in this case in Typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns, scalability

my problem is that I want that Product class implements both classes [Review and Category] to get more scalability in my code. However, I got stuck in that. I tried to use even Mixins but I had to re-assign all methods from Category and Review, Does anyone knows a better and smart solution to do so?

```
interface Fetch {
    getInfo() :string;
}

class Review implements Fetch {

    getInfo(): string {
        return 'Nice Product'
    }

    getName(): string {
        return 'Shirt Star wars'
    }

    geRate(): string {
        return '5 stars'
    }
}

class Category implements Fetch {

    getInfo(): string {
        return 'Nice Category'
    }

    getCategory(): string {
        return 'Geek'
    }

    getSimilar(): string[] {
        return []
    }
}

class Product extends Review {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

let Shirt = new Product()

Shirt.getInfo()
Shirt.geRate()
```

Comment: How about CategoryInterface and ReviewInterface, now implement them in Category and Review, while both in Product ?

Comment: Could give me an example to clarify? cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you have asked:

```
interface Fetch {
    getInfo() :string;
}

interface ReviewInterface extends Fetch{

    getName(): string;

    getRate(): string;
}

interface CategoryInterface extends Fetch{


    getCategory(): string;

    getSimilar(): string[];
}

class Review implements ReviewInterface {

    getInfo(): string {
        return 'Nice Product'
    }

    getName(): string {
        return 'Shirt Star wars'
    }

    geRate(): string {
        return '5 stars'
    }
}

class Category implements CategoryInterface {

    getInfo(): string {
        return 'Nice Category'
    }

    getCategory(): string {
        return 'Geek'
    }

    getSimilar(): string[] {
        return []
    }
}

class Product implements ReviewInterface, CategoryInterface {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    // .... Here goes all implementations...
}

let Shirt = new Product()

Shirt.getInfo()
Shirt.geRate()
```

Comment: Is this case inheritance over composition?

Comment: I mean that, composition over inheritance. hahaha

Comment: Right, make lot of sense this implementation and looks like mixins but my class Product must implement all interface methods. I mean, despite the relation between classes is not bad re-implement the same methods of Category class inside Product class again?

Comment: Is category to product 1 on 1 relation? If yes then this will be overkill. But AFA I think it should inherit Review not Category.